# Align paragraphs inside the 'Acknowledgements' environment

Tags: acknowledgements

I would like to know how to align paragraphs inside the 'Acknowledge' environment. Follow below a print of the PDF:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to remove the indentation from the second paragraph onward, or to add it in the first?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to say it. I would like to add the indentation in the first paragraph.